# hooks sharp enough to make Peter Pan wet his tights

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

*These contributions-- his two solo albums, The Madcap Laughs and Barrett, both released in 1970-- transcend his work with late-60s Pink Floyd and make for haunting aural documents of a prolific talent's dilapidating psyche while paradoxically managing to retain a rich charm and **hooks sharp enough to make Peter Pan wet his tights**.*

Source: https://pitchfork.com/reviews/albums/568-wouldnt-you-miss-me-the-best-of/

Does an allusion to Peter Pan have any particular meaning in the review? I do know how to interpret it within the context.  Is "to make Peter Pan wet his tight" some sort of a metaphor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A musical hook is a part of a melody that's catchy and often repeated, intended to 'hook' somebody into listening to song because it's recognizable.

Peter Pan's arch enemy was Captain Hook, who had a hook for a hand.

As such, the writer is using a play on the word hook to make a joke. He's saying the hooks in the song are so sharp that if you imagined them as Captain Hook, he would be so fearsome that Peter Pan would be afraid of him and wet himself.